# com.dashlane.DashlaneAgent still trying to be loaded

Tags: launchd, startup

I have removed Dashlane using the documented procedure, yet launchd is still trying to load com.dashlane.DashlaneAgent. I have tried issuing `sudo launchctl remove com.dashlane.DashlaneAgent` with no success (the command succeeds, and `launchctl list` does not show the service, but upon reboot, a `list` again contains the service name). I've also looked in `/private/var/db/launchd.db` and not found any entries for this service.

I did find lines for this service in `/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd` in both `loginitems.501.plist` and `disabled.501.plist`. When I remove those lines and reboot, they simply reappear.

So this service launch is coming from somewhere; does anyone know where?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `Dashlane` was still in my `.Trash`; deleting it from `.Trash` solved the problem. I don't understand why; perhaps someone else does; but it seems worth recording here.

Comment: Same here. When I emptied the trash it stopped.